# preg_match problem

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a schedule system that collects information from a RSS feed. However, when I try to strip the necessary segment from the RSS preg_match returns it as invalid.

```
//Finds the day by stripping data from the myDragonnet RSS feed.
function schedule($given_date) {
    $url = "http://mydragonnet.hkis.edu.hk/schedule/day_schedule_rss.php?schedule_id=1";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $date = date("~jS M Y~", strtotime($given_date)); 
    if($rss) {
        foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
            foreach ($item->title as $story) {
                if (strpos($date, $story) !== false) {
                    preg_match("/Day (\d+)/", $story, $m);
                    break; // stop searching
                }   
            } 
        }
    }
    return $m[1];
}
```

The function : `<?php echo schedule('01/24/2010'); ?>`

This is the error I'm getting -

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '/' in ***/class.schedule.php on line 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
// Finds the day by stripping data from the myDragonnet RSS feed.
function schedule($given_date) {
    $url = "http://mydragonnet.hkis.edu.hk/schedule/day_schedule_rss.php?schedule_id=1";
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $date = date("jS M Y", strtotime($given_date)); 
    $found = false;

    if($rss) {
        foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
            foreach ($item->title as $story) {
                if (strpos($story, $date) !== false) {
                    if (preg_match('/Day (\d+)/i', $story, $m)) {
                        $found = true;
                        break; // stop searching
                    }
                }   
            }

            if ($found)
            {
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    return $m[1];
}
```

Comment: I actually solved this yesterday but your method certainly helps!

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is that `preg_match` expects its first argument (the pattern) to be enclosed in pair of delimiters say `/the pattern/`

So change:

```
preg_match($date, $story)
```

to

```
preg_match('!'.preg_quote($date).'!', $story)
```

---

Also it looks like you are using `preg_match` to just search for a string in another string. It is better to use a string searching function like `strpos` or `strstr` for such a thing:

```
if (strpos($date, $story) === false) 
   continue;
```

You can rewrite your `foreach` loop as

```
foreach ($item->title as $story) {
        if (strpos($date, $story) !== false) {
            echo $story;             
            break; // stop searching
        }   
}
```

Comment: Will I remove the ! before preg_match?

Comment: Thanks...sorry I'm pretty pathetic when it comes to this...MUCH APPRECIATED

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `strstr()` instead of preg_match. It's much faster! ([Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php))